# 複数の要素がある配列の特定の値を参照してソート

Tags: java, array, sort

私はJava初心者です。
現在いくつかの問題を解いてるのですが、ある問題で詰まってしまいました。
そこで有識者の方々に意見をお伺いしたいと思い、質問させていただきました。

今回、クラスを用いて入力した値を参照してデータを昇順にソートしたいと考えています。
データとしては【氏名、性別、職業、年齢】といったデータを５個入力し、年齢部分の値を使ってソートしたいと考えています。
しかし１つの配列のデータのみの値でしたらソート出来るのですが、このように複数の配列があるデータを複数用いてソートするというのが分かりません。

考えたり、調べてもやり方が浮かばなかったので意見を貰えると幸いです。

【田中優、男、会社員、２６】
【遠藤仁美、女性、高校生、１５】
【加藤博史、男性、自営業、４４】

という例をソートして

【遠藤仁美、女性、高校生、１５】
【田中優、男、会社員、２６】
【加藤博史、男性、自営業、４４】

というように年齢を参照してソートしたいです。

この場合、年齢部分を参照してソートはどうやって出来るのでしょうか？
色々なソートを試したのですが、どうしても上手くいきませんでした。

```
   class HumanData{
    private String name;
    private String sex;
    private String profession;
    int age;
    
    public void setFields(String n, String s, String p, int a) {
        name = n;
        sex = s;
        profession = p;
        age = a;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getSex() {
        return sex;
    }
    
    public String Profession() {
        return profession;
    }
    
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("氏名：" + name + "、性別:" + sex + "、職業:" + profession + "、年:" + age + "");
    }

}


public class Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        MusicData[] data = new HumanData[2];
        
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("データを入力してください");
            String H_name = br.readLine();
            String H_sex = br.readLine();
            String H_profession = br.readLine();
            String H_age = br.readLine();
            int ag = Integer.parseInt(H_age);
            data[i] = new HumanData();
            data[i].setFields(H_name, H_sex, H_profession, ag);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
            data[i].show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

簡単なソート方法として、[`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,java.util.Comparator))と[`Comparator.comparingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))を組み合わせて特定メソッドの戻り値でソート可能です。

**サンプルコード**(HumanDataは変更していないため省略)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Data {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HumanData[] data = new HumanData[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {data[i] = new HumanData();}  // 配列を初期化

        data[0].setFields("田中優","男","会社員",26);
        data[1].setFields("遠藤仁美","女","高校生",15);
        data[2].setFields("加藤博史","男","自営業",44);

        // ソート
        Arrays.sort(data, Comparator.comparingInt(HumanData::getAge));

        // 表示
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
            data[i].show();
        }
    }
}
```

**参考資料**

- [Java8のComparatorの使い方(Collectionsクラスのsortメソッド)](https://confrage.jp/java8%E3%81%AEcomparator%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9collections%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A9%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AEsort%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89/)
- [Sort a Java collection object based on one field in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12542755)

Comment: 無事に動作し、解決いたしました。回答していただきありがとうございます！